# UISplitViewController side panel nav bar

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I need to include a static, non-collapsible navigation bar on the left side of a UISplitViewController with the normal master and detail views. I've tried adding a third column to the split view for the side bar, but I'm not able to disable the collapse of the side bar column.

**My Question**

Is it possible to disable any collapse of a column of the UISplitViewController?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

**Note:**
One thought I've had is to not use a split view at all and build a custom solution since it doesn't seem like disabling the collapse of a single column is possible.

Comment: I lost the code due to a better solution, but *yes* you can prevent the side bar from collapsing. (The default on iPads is to automatically collapse the primary view when rotating from landscape to portrait.) IIRC, it involves (a) tracking if the sidebar is being displayed, (b) changes in rotation, and (c) properly calling `show(.primary)`. I tried making a VC be a delegate of the split view VC but really didn't have much luck.

Comment: Final notes. (1) I was assuming you are targeting iOS 14, as there are features there that may not apply to prior versions. (2) You also have another option, which is the one I took. Use a `UISplitViewController`, but don't declare a primary VC. Just use a secondary and compact VC and (as you indicated) roll your own side bar inside the secondary VC.